# GPO settings to enable termination of a remote process using Powershell

Tags: powershell, process, gpo

I have a Server 2012 server with a network of windows 7 machines.  I am attempting to run the following powershell code to terminate a remote process such as paint.exe:

```
$computer = 'some-computer'
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer) | ?{$_ProcessName -ilike 'mspaint*' }).Terminate()
```

This gives a return value of 2, which is Access Denied.  I've found that this is caused by something in the GPO Baseline Windows 7 Policy because when I disable it the command works.  I've tried changing dozens of GPO settings that could be related but It's like looking for a needle in a haystack.  Any ideas on which policy could be blocking access, or what GPO settings would enable access?  Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `Get-Process -ComputerName $computer -Name 'mspaint' | Stop-Process` instead of a WMI call?

Comment: I believe stop-process is only supported when run on a local machine, it cannot be sent as a remote command to another machine.

Comment: Is WS-Man (PSRemoting) enabled on your machines?

Comment: Yes, I use invoke-command for a variety of other tasks.  enable-psremoting has been run successfully on all my clients.

Comment: I'd suggest using `Invoke-Command -cn $computer { Get-Process 'mspaint' | Stop-Process }` then

Comment: I can run get-process through invoke-command but piping to stop-process gives an access denied error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158004/discussion-between-theincorrigible1-and-lee-exothermix).